# index option for glossaries-extra doesn't work with memoir?

Tags: memoir, indexing, glossaries-extra

I am using memoir to create a thesis, and using glossaries-extra to make an acronym-type glossary.

I now want to use glossaries-extra to create an index too, (MWE is replicated from the glossaries-extra manual) but when I add in the index option for glossaries-extra, I get error

> line 1953 Command \printindex already defined

How can I get around this?
I know I could use memoir inbuilt index commands but would prefer to use glossaries-extra for both glossary and index.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[
nomain,
acronym,
%index % Command \printindex already defined
]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{laser}{laser}{light amplification by stimulated
    emission of radiation}

\begin{document}
    \gls{laser}
    \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Many thanks,
Conor

Comment: You should probably send the maintainer of `glossaries-extra` an email. For now something like `\let\printindex\relax` before loading `glossaries-extra` might work

Comment: Thank you, that has worked as a temporary measure